# Why separation of *.py and *.h/*.lisp auto generated messages?

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
this must be a rather obvious thing but I am still not sure about. Why are all auto-generated *.lisp and *.h msgs placed in msg_gen folder but *.py ones into src/pkg_name/ folder?

thx, D.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10227/why-separation-of-*.py-and-*.h/*.lisp-auto-generated-messages?/) by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1420 on 2011-06-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

msg_gen is a better location as it keeps auto-generated code separate from actual source code, but some languages make it more difficult to combine source files from multiple directories into the same namespace.  For example, if you have two directories in Python, each with name 'package', the first one on your PYTHONPATH will get the 'package' namespace, and the other will be ignored.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0